# pandas DataFrameから特定列の値が複数の候補のいずれかで抽出する方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなpandas DataFrameがあります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(10,3),columns=pd.Index(['one','two','three']))
```

twoカラムで数値が22の行を取得するには以下のようにしています。

```
df[df['two']==22]
```

これは易しいのですが、
twoカラムで数値が10と22と28といった複数行を取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [How do I use within / in operator in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31595372)

Comment: metropolis様　ご紹介いただいた方法で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のように、 `isin` を用いると実現できます。

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                    
   ...: import numpy as np                                                     
   ...: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(10,3),columns=pd.Index(['one','two','three']))
   ...: df
   one  two  three
0    0    1      2                                                             
1    3    4      5
2    6    7      8
3    9   10     11
4   12   13     14
5   15   16     17
6   18   19     20
7   21   22     23                                                             
8   24   25     26
9   27   28     29              

In [4]: df[df['two'].isin((22, 25, 28))]
Out[4]: 
   one  two  three
7   21   22     23
8   24   25     26
9   27   28     29
```